# Scoring call to bet, call to raise, bet and raise plays to generate an index. PLO

Tags: online, omaha

I am making offline analysis of the hands I own after playing sometime online.

I play Omaha only, but this may apply to Texas Holdem too.

I want to generate with code notes of my opponents and insert them on pokertracker database with code.

To simplify it, let's say I want to generate notes for flush projects on flop as:

- Bets a little flush project Flop.
- Bets quite flush project Flop.
- Bets a lot flush project Flop.

I want to know, if my oponnet is raising, how much probably is beting with flush project. That can help me make decissions as playing top double pairs on a flop with two suited cards. If my oponnent never raises with flush project and is raising I can put him on a set and fold my two pair. And viceversa I can pay with my double top pair if a third suited card don't comes.

I know the best here is to use machine learning algorithms, but I don't have so much programing and math knowledges. I want just to aproximate with an index, plot an histogram of the frequency of index of all my oponnents and decide where I put the limits .

The database I generated from hands stores as a boolean (true or false) value:

- Call to bet.
- Call to raise.
- Bets.
- Raises.

I cannot calculate VPIP or AFQ since my data is for hands with showdown. When my oponnents folded I don't know wich cards they had.

To generate my index this are the values I give presently to each play:

- Call to bet. (**3 points**)
- Call to raise. (**5 points**)
- Bets. (**5 points**)
- Raises. (**10 points**)

Do you think the points I give to each play are accurated, or I should change them?

Comment: check out this link, it may answer your question. https://upswingpoker.com/glossary/aggression-frequency-afq/

Comment: @Clarko Thanks, that was what I was searching for. Gonna use AFQ to generate the ntoes.

Comment: @Clarko wait that don't works. My stats come from hands with showdown. Folds are not included as when my oponent folds he don't show cards.

Comment: I offer a bounty in the case you or someone wants to help me to generate the index

Comment: could you be more specific about the term "aggression"? the definition of aggression in poker is the amount of raises or bets divided by the total action. Are you looking for a combination of aggression and vpip? what purpose does this aggression calculation serve in your program?

Comment: @Clarko I would use AFQ index if I had data of folded hands with flush project. The problem is I have not. I can only use those four stats, and I have also stored the % of the pot in any bet or raise. I can use that fifth stat too but I have not fold stats. I don't have knowledges of poker so I don't know. I want to know if they bet a lot, I know that's not very specific. I cannot calculate neither VPIP for the same reasson: I have not stats when they fold their projects.

Comment: Forget agressiveness. I removed it from the question. I hoppe now it is more clear. I want someone tells if the points I give to each play is accurated or may sugest other punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, there is a not a way to do this with an equation because you can not see the hole cards of your opponents unless you go to showdown (which does not apply to your scenario because you want to know if they are folding to a flush draw). It could be more feasible to do this against a single opponent given that they play a specific line when they have a flush draw and bet with recognizable patterns.

I do not play much PLO, but there are definitely board textures and betting patterns that would make me think another player has a flush draw. My suggestion to you would be to go over hands where your opponent bet/folded or bet/called on a specific street (like the flop) and try and see if you can narrow down what they are holding based on the action in the hand. this way, you will be able to understand the patterns associated with a player having a flush draw. You can then look at any players stats and get useful information from that (assuming you have a decent amount of hands with them).